# Angular 6 what is the difference between @HostBinding('class') and @HostBinding('attr.class')

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding

I'm inspecting the source code of an Angular 6 project and saw the usage of both `@HostBinding('class')` and `@HostBinding('attr.class')`. I changed one of the implementations from `@HostBinding('class')` to `@HostBinding('attr.class')` and did not notice any difference in the rendered result. What are the differences between the two and when should I opt for one implementation over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any meaningful difference between the two in the way you use it, but there is one difference on a conceptual level: using `'class'` takes the class definition of the element, while `'attr.class'` takes the value of the attribute named "class".

By using just `'class'` without attribute, you can then bind specific classes to a boolean, like this:

```
@HostBinding('class.blue')
@Input() blue: boolean;
```

Then, assuming the HostBinding is defined in a directive called `my-directive`, you can use this HTML:

```
<div my-directive [blue]="true"></my-directive>
```

And it would result in a div that contains `class="blue"`

As for which one you should use in your case, it doesn't really matter. I would go with simply `class` because it's shorter, but it really doesn't matter in that case.

Answer (score 1):

`@HostBinding('class')` & `@HostBinding('attr.class')` have the same net effect and using either of these will yield the same result.
@HostBinding can be used to bind to any class, property or attribute on a host element. 
Which syntax you use will be determined by what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to dynamically change a `data-` attribute then you will need to use `@HostBinding('attr.data-special')`.

If you are want to change the disabled state of the element then you would use `@HostBinding('disabled')`.

You can also bind to individual classes using `@HostBinding('class.myClass')` or bind inline styles such as `@HostBinding('style.color')`.